# Twig - determine if mobile agent or not

Tags: php, symfony, mobile, jquery-mobile

I'm developing a site on a platform that's using the Twig (Symfony) language for its templates, and in one place, I need to change the layout (disable a default block and load a different block) based on whether the user is on a mobile device or a desktop.

I know how to do it in PHP (using the "check_user_agent('mobile')" variable), but that doesn't work in Twig... and I've come across a reference to the Twig "Mobile Detect Bundle", but I have no idea how to install it (shared hosting with cPanel).

Soo... is there a way to detect mobile user-agent in Twig, without having to install anything?

Answer (score 3):

#### General Solution for PHP

https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/ is a great and **maintained** php class to detect the user agent and is not limited to Symfony.

#### For Symfony

To use the above class with Symfony, you could either write a [twig extension](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/templating/twig_extension.html) yourself or use this [Mobile Detect Twig Extension](https://github.com/bes89/mobiledetect-twig-extension) that does the job.

Answer (score 1):

During each request, Symfony will set a global template variable app in both Twig and PHP template engines by default. 
The Request object that represents the current request:  **`app.request`**

So if you want to know the user-agent you can use **`app.request.headers`** in the template.
e.g :

```
{{ app.request.headers.get('User-Agent')}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have PHP code to return true/false based on the user agent, it is quite simple to [Write a custom Twig Extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html) to run that code, but from Twig.

Alternatively, you can run the check in the controller and pass in the result, or in a 'kernel.controller Event' to even run the check before a controller action is called (probably putting it into a Request 'attributes', where it can also be checked in the template).

Comment: I think @snela, @alisterbulman is right... You can resolve your problem with  `Twig Extension`.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use the Mobile Detect Bundle and you want to detect mobile in Twig here is a solution:

```
    {% if 'iPhone' in app.request.headers.get('User-Agent') 
        or 'iPod' in app.request.headers.get('User-Agent') 
        or 'iPad' in app.request.headers.get('User-Agent') 
        or 'Android' in app.request.headers.get('User-Agent') 
        or 'BlackBerry' in app.request.headers.get('User-Agent') %}
            <h1>Hi, I see this using Mobile Device</h1>
    {% else %}
            <h1>Hi, I see this because im not using Mobile Device</h1>
    {% endif %}
```